# Ubuntu router returns ICMP administratively prohibited for all IPv6

Tags: networking, server, ipv6

I am using an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, named ubu1404-150805-3, as a dual-stacked (IPv4 and IPv6) router.  I have a client machine, named ubu1404-150805-2, that is also Ubuntu 14.04 and whose only network access is through that Ubuntu router.  This all works fine for IPv4.  But whenever the client tries to send an IPv6 packet to anything besides the router, the router returns an ICMP packet of type 3, code 9 (administratively prohibited).  The client *can* `ping6` the router.  What is going wrong and how do I fix it?

On the Ubuntu router there are no ip6tables rules, and the only iptables rule does SNAT:

```
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Sep 27 03:35:36 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [33:3275]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4:744]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [17:1207]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:60]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep 27 03:35:36 2015
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~# ip6tables-save
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~#
```

The router has two NICs, one for upstream and one for downstream.  It has no native IPv6 service from upstream, so I also installed miredo there.  The router has no problem doing IPv6 things itself:

```
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~# ping6 -c 1 2001:4860:4860::8844
PING 2001:4860:4860::8844(2001:4860:4860::8844) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=289 ms

--- 2001:4860:4860::8844 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 289.616/289.616/289.616/0.000 ms
```

For comparison, here is the client failing at that:

```
mspreitz@ubu1404-150805-2:~$ ping6 -c 1 2001:4860:4860::8844
PING 2001:4860:4860::8844(2001:4860:4860::8844) 56 data bytes
From fddf:2::1 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited

--- 2001:4860:4860::8844 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

`tcpdump -i eth1` on the router shows the ping request coming in and the "administratively prohibited" going back to the client.

`tcpdump -i teredo` on the router shows that it forwards the client's ping request!  And no ping reply is seen.

```
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~# tcpdump -nne -i teredo
tcpdump: WARNING: teredo: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on teredo, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes
03:57:39.349401 ip: fddf:2::b9ca:b0dc:8ae:4002 > 2001:4860:4860::8844: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 64
```

Here is `ip addr` from the router:

```
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e0:d0:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee0:d0b2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f7:66:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.100.1/24 brd 10.0.100.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fddf:2::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef7:664a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: teredo: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet6 2001:0:53aa:64c:28fd:345a:d0ed:e570/32 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ffff:ffff:ffff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And here is the config on the client:

```
mspreitz@ubu1404-150805-2:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:72:df:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.100.2/24 brd 10.0.100.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fddf:2::b9ca:b0dc:8ae:4002/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 85988sec preferred_lft 13988sec
    inet6 fddf:2::a00:27ff:fe72:df14/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 85988sec preferred_lft 13988sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe72:df14/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The router is configured to forward unicast IPv4 and IPv6 packets:

```
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~# sysctl -a | grep forward
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.teredo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.teredo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.teredo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.teredo.mc_forwarding = 0
```

And the router has IPv6 privacy turned off:

```
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~# sysctl -a | grep tempaddr
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.teredo.use_tempaddr = -1
```

I doubt it matters, but I am running radvd and rdnssd on the router.  The client is configured in `/etc/network/interfaces` using the static method for both IPv4 and IPv6, with `autoconf 1` (i.e., enabling SLAAC) in the v6 case.

Here is the version information from the server:

```
root@ubu1404-150805-3:~# uname -a
Linux ubu1404-150805-3 3.13.0-61-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And it is the same on the client:

```
mspreitz@ubu1404-150805-2:~$ uname -a
Linux ubu1404-150805-2 3.13.0-61-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

BTW, both of these machines are VirtualBox (version 4.3.30) VMs.  I use a VirtualBox internal network on the server's eth1 and the client's eth0.  The server's eth0 is NATted to the host, a Mac running MacOS 10.10.5.

Answer (score 0):

Teredo only provides IPv6 for the host itself so you can't use it to provide IPv6 on your LAN. If you want subnets you can route you should use a tunnel service like tunnelbroker.net or SixXS.

Besides, Teredo is a horribly unreliable protocol.

Comment: Ah, right: a Teredo tunnel only provides a path back to the Teredo client IPv6 address, and IPv6 don't need no stinkin' NAT, so the Teredo tunnels from my router can not provide a return path for connections from my client.

Comment: Thanks, Sander, I voted your answer up.  But this site does not (yet) deem my votes worthy of showing.